# Question about development of 3-D svg file in my Croquet Player Game

Tags: svg, blender

My challenge is **not** Swift. My challenge is the development of the 3-D svg dynamic file using Blender.

I have worked with Blender a small amount and its use is currently intimidating

**I am developing a Game Controller activated game called Croquet Player.**

The proposed game sequence is as follows:

[1] Using Swift, the Game Controller moves the Player toward the Ball = ***done***

[2] The  dynamic svg Blender file takes over and rotates the Player such that his head is always facing the Ball **and** moves the Mallet in such a way that the flat head of the Mallet is pointed at the Ball = ***not done***

[3] When the Game Controller moves the Player such that the Mallet eventually contacts the Ball, the Swift code hits the Ball and it moves = ***done***

And the above sequence starts over: [1] move Player toward Ball, [2] rotate the Player toward the Ball as it’s moving toward the Ball, **and** repoint Mallet toward the Ball, [3] upon the Mallet actually contacting the Ball, hit it.

Here is a screen shot of a sample of the Player’s & Mallet’s orientations as I just described:

[sample orientations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/frCGc.png)

Comment: Danny - as I explained at the top, Swift code is not my problem, but Blender is. Given that, please recommend where I can post this. I know StackOverflow has a Blender Section. FWIW, many moons ago, I have been zinged for **not** presenting the big picture which in this case is the Game. As soon as I delete my short Game explanation, I promise you that I will be zinged, marked down or whatever by others.

Comment: Found it: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/300828/how-to-develop-a-3-d-svg-dynamic-file-using-blender I wish to keep the above post up there in case there may be others who can provide a suggestion or two. If and only if you **strongly** object, feel free to delete the above yourself